# How to Copy/Move/Delete multiple files and folders in VB.net?

Tags: vb.net

I would like to Copy/Move/Delete multiple files and folders in VB.net using the Microsoft.visualBasic.FileIO.FileSystem methods, with the UIOption.ShowAllDialogs parameter so that I can see the built-in progress window.Currently what I do is just loop through the list of files and folders and call the appropriate method for each item(say filesystem.deletefile), but this would open up separate progress dialogs for each item being deleted, and more annoyingly, it would ask you to confirm the deletion (the yes/no dialog) for each file being deleted.Is there any way to resolve this issue? Thanks for any help in advance.

Edit:
Here is my current code:

```
Dim FilesToBeDeleted As new list(of String)'List of files to be deleted

Private Sub DeleteButton_Clicked() Handles DeleteButton.Click 

For each X in FilesToBeDeleted
   My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile(X,FileIO.UIOption.AllDialogs,        
   FileIO.RecycleOption.SendToRecycleBin)
Next X

End Sub
```

Comment: Show us what have you tried please. Paste some code

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is remove the dialog options. This means that nothing will come up, and all the files will be deleted without letting the user know. If you wanted to let them know, you could make your own notification form even with a progress bar.

Here is what that code would look like:

```
    For Each X In FilesToBeDeleted
        My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile(X)
    Next X
```

Answer (score 0):

```
For Each X In FilesToBeDeleted
    System.IO.File.Delete(X)
Next X
```

You'll have to add a progress bar using **BackgroundWorker** to show the progress of your action.
Or check this link, it migt be helpful in simulating default windows dialog box for these actions: 
[Download Dialog box with progress bar like windows](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17979/Downloading-Files-in-NET-With-All-Information-Prog)

Comment: No.I really want the default windows dialog boxes.I could never achieve the perfection and completion of the default dialogs.There is no way i could imitate the graphics(especially the ones in windows 8).

Comment: Till now didn't find a way for you to use default windows dialog boxes. But you can pretty much simulate them.
This is a link I used once for similar task:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17979/Downloading-Files-in-NET-With-All-Information-Prog

Comment: I am amazed why there is no way for doing such a very simple thing... just copy/delete some files using the built-in features of the OS..There is no simpler problem than this on SO.